# Counting unnecessary words (Unix) using grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I am trying to count the number of times the word fire and water shows up in the last word of each line

```
$cat file 
red,Fire
blue,water 
Fire red, Fire
```

My solution:

```
$grep -Ewo "Fire" <file> | sort | uniq -c
```

the output I get is:

```
$Fire 3
$Water 1
```

What I expected to get is:

```
$Fire 2
$Water 1
```

Comment: That ("Fire 3", "Water 1") is not the output I get when I run that command. I get the word "Fire" printed three times on three separate lines. Can you please post a complete shell session showing what you get and what you expect from each specific command?

Comment: I actually used grep -Ewo "Fire" <file> | sort | uniq -c. My bad i will update it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you're passing to `grep` doesn't match your requirements. `Fire` simply means those letters, in that order, anywhere in the string.

You include the `-w` option, which restricts it to appearing as a separate word, but that can still be anywhere on the line. From `man grep` on my system:

> -w, --word-regexp
>   Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a  non-word  constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

Normally, each line would either be repeated in the output or hidden, but you include the `-o` option. From `man grep` on my system:

> -o, --only-matching
>   Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Note in particular that last clause: if multiple parts of the line match, *they will all be output as separate lines of output*.

Compare:

```
# Match all three words, and output the line if it matches
$ echo 'one two three' | grep -E 'one|two|three'
one two three

# Match all three words, and output the matching parts
$ echo 'one two three' | grep -Eo 'one|two|three'
one
two
three
```

So your command is telling you that the word "fire" appears three times in total, ignoring where on the line, or how many times on each line.

To restrict it to only matching *at the end of the line*, add a `$` to your expression:

```
grep -Ewo 'Fire$'
```

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped!